# Does check in online change the cancelation policy?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, check-in, refunds

I have a general question. Does check-in online affect the cancelation policy (such as refund amount and etc.) or they are not related together? I need to know this since I need to check-in within 48 hours before flight, but I should do pcr test and I am not sure still I will go or not. Anyway if I check in online can I cancel the ticket later with the same condition? I think this is not related to the specific airline and the answer is same.

Comment: Do you have a fully refundable ticket? I’m not sure a general answer would necessarily apply, it would be better to state the airline you’re booked with

Comment: No, my question is not related to the airline. This is general question and the dependency of check in to cancelation. It will be partially refund I know it. My question is whether checking online change it or not?

Comment: My question is whether checking online change it or not or if you check in online could you cancel the ticket?

Comment: Interesting question (also because I discovered one can do a "check-out"). But I think it is airline specific, and as always: fare specific. Log-in in your airline website (also if you didn't book there), and get the exact condition of your ticket. Read carefully (and COVID test may give you more chances). Personally, I would just wait until you know you will take the flight. No need to rush

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi "I would just wait until you know you will take the flight. No need to rush" -> I thought the same until one day I missed my flight because of overbooking :)  [What's the point of checking in several days before a flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/171357/1810)

Answer (score 6):

This depends very much on the fare rules of your specific ticket and terms and conditions of the specific airline. You can certainly cancel the ticket after check in but what exactly happens depends on the details. If you don't cancel and don't fly you are a  "no show". Some airlines have different rules for "no shows" vs "cancel". Some airlines also change rules 24 hours before departure which may or may not be coupled to check in.

I once had to change a return flight and doing this after check-in (for the outbound leg) was substantially cheaper than doing it before check-in. So it can make a difference.

> This is general question and the dependency of check in to cancelation

There is no general answer. Cancellation and refund rules are notoriously complicated. I strongly advise reading the fare rules for the ticket you are considering.

Comment: Cancelation is specific but doing check in and cancel is general question.

Comment: @AhmadTurani It may be a general question, but there is no general applies-to-all-airlines answer. That's the point of Hilmar's response.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica (which is much better than closing the question.)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I voted to close for focus/multiple questions, not for the subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Emirates. They mentioned do not check in online unless you are sure you are going to travel. This means that one should first be sure to go then check in because check in can be done until last minutes.

Comment: Did they tell you what happens if you check in but try to cancel afterward?

Comment: No but I think thd best they deduct again from the refund amount

Answer (score 2):

Checking in online or offline will prevent the passenger from making any free change to their flight with  VivaAerobus. From their [terms and conditions](https://web.vivaaerobus.com/en/info/terms-and-conditions#b4-1):

> Said changes may only be made until 4 (four) hours before the time scheduled for the Service, provided your boarding pass has not already been created.

This made me wonder [What's the point of checking in several days before a flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/171357/1810) (tldr: early check-in helps avoid missing the flight since VivaAerobus notoriously overbook them. When I missed my flight last Christmas because of overbooking, the airline employee confirmed it.).