# Can a flexible ticket be changed after check in?

Tags: air-travel, business-class

I recently read a story about a person in China buying a fully flexible business class ticket, checking in, using the business class lounge, then changing the ticket for a future date. He supposedly has done it several times, after which he returned the ticket for a full refund.

The only time I flew on a fully flexible ticket, the T&Cs said "changeable before or after departure", but I guess after check in is a bit of a grey area. While this story sounds more like an anecdote than something real, I’m wondering whether it’s possible to change a fully flexible ticket after check in. And, if yes, what prevents someone from doing something similar.

Comment: Was this presented as a way to use the services of the business class lounge "for free"? Changing a ticket at the last minute doesn't seem especially unusual, unless this was done without the intention of ever actually flying.

Comment: I’ve wondered the same thing many times, but have never been in that situation. Now, on an incumbent, on a full fare ticket (“Y” fare class in coach), given the astronomical prices of those, I wouldn’t be surprised if that was actually allowed, or at least used to be. No idea what the situation actually is (probably varies by airline, and depending on the exact fare class — some flexible fares are more flexible than others).

Comment: It may also depend on the passenger's status with the airline.  I know of a guy who has top status with an airline and has checked-in, gone through security etc., used lounges, met with some friends or clients traveling, and then canceled the flight for a full refund and left the airport.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is **absolutely possible to make changes after checkin**.  The catch is, you can't just do this self-service, once you've been checked in you will almost certainly need **assistance from airline staff to make any changes**.

Since the plural of anecdote is data, a couple of cases where I've had my flights changed after checkin, from pedestrian to more unusual:

- Flying in from NY, I missed a connection at SFO, so I was given a new boarding pass at the lounge for a later flight.  Very common.
- Flight to Jakarta with a long-ish connection in Bali, both boarding passes issued at origin.  I arrived well ahead of schedule and realized I could catch an earlier flight, so I talked to the lounge staff and they made it happen.  Not so common but still easy-peasy.
- Checked in online in the morning for a flight at night, but a family member  suddenly gets sick.  I called up the airline, they "un-check-in" us, split the itinerary so the rest could still travel, and issued new tickets.  Took a while, but straight forward.

Finally, the story you mention that made the rounds in 2014 involved somebody supposedly using the China Eastern first-class lounge in Xi'an over 300 times in one year.  Sadly if unsurprisingly, [it has been debunked](http://www.thatsmags.com/china/post/3089/no-a-first-class-passenger-didnt-eat-for-free-for-a-year), China has strict security at airports and the article claims that no changes are allowed once your physical boarding pass is issued.  As noted above, this is actually false, but what *is* true is that they would not have been able to quietly change their flights *by themselves*, and they certainly would have been noticed if they had asked staff to make changes 300 times in a row!

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the airline. E.g., checking in online or offline will prevent the passenger from making any free change to their flight with  VivaAerobus. From their [terms and conditions](https://web.vivaaerobus.com/en/info/terms-and-conditions#b4-1):

> Said changes may only be made until 4 (four) hours before the time scheduled for the Service, provided your boarding pass has not already been created.

This made me wonder [What's the point of checking in several days before a flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/171357/1810) (tldr: early check-in helps avoid missing the flight since VivaAerobus notoriously overbook them. When I missed my flight last Christmas because of overbooking, the airline employee confirmed it.).